Elasticsearch match_phrase query with 100% match
Search term: marble floor
Document 1
{
   "title": "marble floor"
}

Document 2
{
   "title": "floor marble"
}

Document 3
{
    "title": "marble floor light"
}

query which I have used
{
    "_source": [
        "title"
    ],
    "size": 10,
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "should": [
                {
                    "match_phrase": {
                        "title": {
                            "query": "marble floor",
                            "boost": 1
                        }
                    }
                }
            ],
            "minimum_should_match": "1"
        }
    }
}  

Expected result:
Document 1 & Document 2. If I use a .keyword, it doesn't undergo stemming or any other analysis steps. Guide me with some solutions.

So you want match phrase but the order of words can be jumbled?



Keyword fields are often used in sorting, aggregations, and term-level
queries, such as term.
Avoid using keyword fields for full-text search. Use the text field
type instead.
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/keyword.html


.keyword field types are not analyzed and tokened as is. To understand the concept, I recommend you to use _analyze API call and see the result.
You can use text field type instead.
GET /_analyze
{
  "analyzer" : "standard",
  "text" : "marble floor"
}

---
GET /_analyze
{
  "tokenizer" : "keyword",
  "text" : "marble floor"
}

